# Java src structure

Tags: java, structure, project

Is it possible to flatten sections of the src tree?

For example, I have these classes:

```
com.company.project.package1.class1
com.company.project.package1.class2
com.company.project.package2.class1
```

These are typically arranged as:

```
src/com/company/project/package1/class1
src/com/company/project/package1/class2
src/com/company/project/package2/class1
```

but this produces lots of empty pointless folders. What I'd like to do is structure it as:

```
src/com.company.project/package1/class1
src/com.company.project/package1/class2
src/com.company.project/package2/class1
```

Is that possible and if so, how? I using Eclipse but answers for other environments would be welcome too.

Comment: these folders are not empty, they have their subpackages in them

Comment: Java maps package names to directory hierachies, so I would not call these directories "pointless" as they reflect your package hierarchy.

Comment: Eclipse does exactly that in its Package Explorer view. Isn't that enough to streamline your development process?

Comment: I know that the IDEs can display the data nicely but I like to have tidy folders too and having a deep chain of nested folders with no files in just seems wrong. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is that possible.

In theory, you could rewrite the Java compiler, Eclipse and other tools in the Java tool-chain to work that way.  If you had a few months of spare time to spend on this ... and you were prepared to maintain your "fork" of the tools indefinitely.

In practice, it is not possible.  No existing Java tool-chains support this way of organizing packages,

Comment: Lol, thanks. I know that I could rewrite the compiler but all I was looking for was an option switch.